# Tag for general UX questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I tried to come up with a tag for questions relating to the ux field itself - its career, training and other general aspects. I'd call it "meta", but, well, that's obviously not a very bright idea. For the time being I went for [ux-field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-field) and tagged a few questions. I don't think it's the perfect term for it - maybe someone has a better idea?

P.S. In case you think that questions like that are off-topic, please flag/vote to close them, or open a separate question on Meta. This one is about **the wording of the tag**.

P.P.S. The subject doesn't mean "general questions on the subject of UX", but rather "specific questions on the general subject of UX" - which aren't the same thing.

Comment: Towards the end it occurred to me that P.S. could well stand for Preventive Strike :)

Comment: This is a good discussion to have as it led to the creation of programmers.SE when StackOverflow went through the same debate. Obviously we don't have a large enough community to support creation of (another) subcommunity, so it's worth discussing how we should approach this.

Comment: I would say flag or *vote to close* if you can. We need more of the community to get involved in moderating.

Comment: @Patrick done, you're right.

Answer (score 2):

You're right: It's a meta tag, and by any other name it would still be meta.

Most of the questions would fit under [career-development](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development). We have a [career](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career) tag, but "career-development" is less ambiguous and can also cover education and training that precede employment in the field.

Comment: I'm also leaning towards looking for specific tags that represent each individual question rather than blanketing them with a meta tag.